# SQL Listing item without repeating first one

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table that has assignment names
ex:

```
contact_task#   ContactName
984             Michael  
984             Andrew 
984             Steve
984             Paul
```

I wanted to create a query based on the above so that i get something like this

```
Contact_task#   ContactName   OtherContact
984             Michael       Andrew, Steve, Paul

984             Andrew        Michael, Steve, Paul

984             Steve         Michael, Andrew, Paul

984             PAul          Michael, Andrew, Steve
```

I have started it but i can't get the contactName to not appear again on the other contact

```
select a.Contact_task, a.ContactName, OtherContact
from contacttable a

 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT xx.Contact_task,
                          rtrim(MAX(decode(rn,
                                           1,
                                           xx.ContactName)) || ', ' ||
                                MAX(decode(rn,
                                           2,
                                           xx.ContactName)) || ', ' ||
                                MAX(decode(rn,
                                           3,
                                           xx.ContactName)) || ', ' ||
                                MAX(decode(rn,
                                           4,
                                           xx.ContactName)) || ', ' ||
                                MAX(decode(rn,
                                           5,
                                           xx.ContactName)) || ', ' ||
                                MAX(decode(rn,
                                           6,
                                           xx.ContactName)),
                                ', ') AS OtherContact
                     FROM (SELECT a.Contact_task,
                               ContactName,
                                  row_number() over(PARTITION BY a.Contact_task ORDER BY ContactName ) rn
                             FROM contacttable a

                          ) xx
                    GROUP BY xx.Contact_task) y ON a.Contact_task =
                                                  y.Contact_task


where a.Contact_task = '984'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it -

```
WITH data
     AS (SELECT 984 id, 'M' name FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 984 id, 'A' name FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 984 id, 'S' name FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 984 id, 'P' name FROM DUAL)
  SELECT d1.id,
         d1.name,
         LISTAGG (d2.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d2.name) other
    FROM data d1
         JOIN data d2 ON d1.id = d2.id AND d1.name <> d2.name
GROUP BY d1.id, d1.name;
```

Basically, I have joined the table to itself with the condition that ID is the same but names are not. That way, in your example, `ID:984, Name:Michael` would be joined to 3 rows based on the same ID and different name - `Andrew,Steve,and Paul`.

Then all you need to do is a `GROUP BY` and `LISTAGG` on the other names.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about MySQL...  in Oracle:

```
with assignment_names (contact_task#, ContactName) as
   ( select 984, 'Michael' from dual union all
     select 984, 'Andrew'  from dual union all
     select 984, 'Steve'   from dual union all
     select 984, 'Paul'    from dual union all
     select 990, 'Mary'    from dual union all
     select 990, 'Joseph'  from dual)
select contact_task#, 
       ContactName, 
       (select listagg(contactName, ', ') within group (order by ContactName)
        from assignment_names a1
        where a1.contact_task# = a.contact_task# and a1.ContactName != a.ContactName
        group by a1.contact_task#) as OtherContacts
from assignment_names a
/
```

**Output**:

```
CONTACT_TASK# CONTACT OTHERCONTACTS
------------- ------- ---------------------------
          984 Michael Andrew, Paul, Steve
          984 Andrew  Michael, Paul, Steve
          984 Steve   Andrew, Michael, Paul
          984 Paul    Andrew, Michael, Steve
          990 Mary    Joseph
          990 Joseph  Mary
```

Comment: Isn't that the same query as mine ;-)

Comment: Certainly the same concept - just implemented differently. I use correlated subqueries instead of a self-join; I am not sure which should be more efficient. (I did see your answer after I posted mine and wondered if I should delete mine, but they are, in fact, not identical...)

Comment: thank you mathguy. I will try this. Also I am assuming where you listed the # and the names, I can replace them with the table name?

Comment: ruudvan I didn't see your answer

Comment: @mathguy, I know it isn't exactly the same. See the winky smiley at the end there. Just meant as a tongue in cheek comment.

Comment: Yes, I know. And you posted before me - no worries. I just tested, and due to different query structure, at least on my machine and with the given data, my query runs about twice as fast as yours. I always like to have more than one solution and to test them side by side. The OP can test on his full-table data, it is possible your query will run faster than mine.

Comment: Thank you all, appreciate it. I will try and let you know.

Comment: @user3139937 - if all your data already exists in a table, you don't need the WITH clause at the top; the query starts at SELECT...   The table name is in the last line (replace "assignment_name" with your actual table name), **note that it is ALSO used three lines above that**, you must substitute in both places. And if your column names are also different, you can replace them in the query.

Comment: @user3139937 - if you use Oracle, please edit your question to remove the MySQL tag (I assume it was added automatically); otherwise MySQL folks will find your post and they will "yell" at you about the tag.

Comment: @ruudvan - to clarify: You posted before I did. I was working on my solution, I posted it, and when the page refreshed I saw there were two answers already, including yours which is a correct answer. Then I wondered if I should delete mine (since yours was posted first) but then I realized they aren't entirely the same. That's what I meant earlier, sorry it wasn't very clear how I meant it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you'd ever want to do this, but anyway...

```
SELECT x.*
     , GROUP_CONCAT(y.contactname) others 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.contact_task = x.contact_task 
   AND y.contactname <> x.contactname 
 GROUP  
    BY contact_task,contactname;
```